# How to achieve this melty glitch effect?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, glitch

The main glitch effect in the following is easy enough to recreate but I am stumped on how you might achieve this melty effect without simply drawing it on. It looks like its using some kind of dust texture but the way it's distorting the edges makes it seem like it hasn't been simply placed over it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For that specific effect that you highlighted, it's difficult to tell what was done to it. But there's a method that could get you close perhaps.

Duplicate the artwork so you have two layers, each with an Ocean Ripple filter but with different settings for each layer, then the top layer set to Linear Dodge, or another blending mode.

Example

[image]

Comment: the original image probably also incorporates layer masks, possibly blocked out with a gradient added left-to-right, possibly on each duped layer.

Comment: @Yorik I totally agree, but in this answer I was only addressing the area highlighted by the OP.